# the rude quote from South Park

Tags: slang

> *Eat penguin shit you ass spelunker.*

First of all I apologize for a little bit inappropriate question given its obscene content. In the movie South Park: Bigger, Longer & Uncut (1999) we can hear the above sentence. I would like to ask whether it has the literal meaning and thus it has really to do with eating animal excrement or it is some sort of the figurative language. Our official translator interpreted this sentence as "fuck the pinguin to the ear, you fug" which I find to be funnier, more absurd and black-humored than its literal (scatological) meaning.

Comment: It's meant to be a degrading imperative. It's up to the person upon whom it is bestowed to take  literally or figuratively.  But **ass-spelunker** must be figurative, unless you're in Brobdingnag.

Comment: Ass-spelunker might be synonymous with sodomy... never thought of it until now, or maybe it's just "someone who is up their own arse"

Comment: The thought of South Park having an "official" translator is fugging hilarious.

Comment: I don't understand your mocking notion. There is one concrete translator who translated all the episodes of South Park and whose translation to my native language is used both in dabing and television as well as on DVDs. I don't know how alternatively I should express this fact than using "official".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only literal to the extent that any vulgar insult or expletive is literal.
The exact meaning depends on when it is used, but in most cases it means something to the effect of a very emphatic and rude way to tell someone to go away, or that you hate them so much you wish something horrible to happen to them.  Eating shit would be pretty horrible.  The penguin was just inserted to make it more absurd.

Other similar phrases would be "Fuck off", "get fucked", "die in a fire".

'Ass-spelunker' is a creative way to describe sodomy.  In this instance it's used a homophobic insult against the recipient of the line.